# SMTP server error inside SMTP Authentication Support in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, smtp

I'm using SMTP Authentication Support in Drupal 7 to send mails. I'm getting this message in my watch dog log for some mail ids. `"Error sending e-mail from example@example.com to recp@example.com : StartTLS not supported by server or could not initiate session`."

What is the possible issue behind this error and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already told you the StartTLS is not supported, call your hosting and let them turn it on. But my guess is they won't. You can use PHPMailer to send the email and don't forget `$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;`